# jxl add Duration Cell

Tags: jxl

I'm trying to add a Duration cell to my sheet.
I use the following code to acomplish this.

```
private void addurationCell(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, long millies) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {

    double durationInDays = (double) millies / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(DateFormats.FORMAT8);

    Number number = new Number(column, row, durationInDays, cellFormat);

    sheet.addCell(number);

}
```

The only problem I have is that it doesn't work for durations longer than one 24 hours...

Using this:

```
DateFormat dfDuration = new DateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

seems not to work.
The only thing that solves the problem is this format

```
    DateFormat dfDuration = new DateFormat("d hh:mm:ss");
```

but this is not verry nice...

Can anyone help me with that?

cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dfDuration = new DateFormat("[h]:mm:ss");
```

from here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190633